# Buscar objetos aleatorios usando condições

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, active-record, rails4

Quero buscar por exemplo 10 pessoas aleatorias do mesmo partido
fiz da seguinte forma, mas esta selecionando pessoas de todos os partidos, o que pode ser feito? =D

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base

    class << self
        def filtra_pessoas()
            Pessoa.where('rand()', partido: "sem partido").first(10)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, basta passar o `rand()` como `order`. Exemplo:

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base

    class << self
        def filtra_pessoas()
            Pessoa.where(partido: "sem partido").order('rand()').first(10)
        end
    end
end
```

GG

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.
quando uso esse metodo novamente ele nao lista, só substitui a busca
sabe dizer como posso resolver isso? =D

exemplo:
filtra_pessoas() // busca "10" pessoas "sem partido"
filtra_pessoas() // busca "8" pessoa de "tal partido"

no caso ele esta buscando só a ultima chamada do metodo

Comment: @ErasmoSantos cria outra pergunta e explica direitinho que te ajudo :D